# ¿Como puedo marca la ruta de un directorio padre o hermano desde un directorio hijo en una url interna en CSS?

Tags: html, css, url

Tengo este problema: estoy en un directorio llamémoslo *css/* y ese directorio tiene un directorio padre que es *res/* y *res/* tiene dos hijos que son *css/* y *img/*, entonces de *css/* quiero acceder a *img/* el cual es su hermano.

He intentado esto poner este valor como `background-image` en un selector: `url('res/img/una-imagen.png')` para acceder a la imagen pero no funcionan, el navegador lo toma como `.../WorkSpace/res/css/res/una-imagen.png` y claro esta mal, si alguien tiene otra forma o alguna idea de acceder a la imagen **pero que no sea con la ruta completa** me la puede pasar por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera url('../img/una-imagen.png')
Si no me equivoco con dos punto estás indicando que empresa a buscar desde una carpeta padre desde donde lo estás solicitando

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me ha servido, espero que esta entrada le pueda servir a alguien mas.